# Can I Redirect Console Output to File Only Keeping Last Line?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, io-redirection

I know I can redirect the output from console to a file like so:

```
myExecutable.exe > myFile.txt
```

where myExecutable is a program that outputs an integer to console every second until killed.

However, the text file will continue to grow longer and longer as it stores all the output it receives until killed. Overwriting the file only occurs at the first like, subsequent lines just append.

I only want the text file to store the very last line output to console. In other words, I want line 1 to output to the text file, then line 2 to overwrite it, then line 3 to overwrite that... Is that possible?

Comment: What about `for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ('myExecutable.exe') do set "LastLine=%%I"` to run `myExecutable.exe` in background using a separate command process started with `%ComSpec% /c myExecutable.exe` with capturing every output line to handle __STDOUT__ and processing the captured output after started `cmd.exe` terminated itself after `myExecutable.exe` terminated itself. Empty lines are ignored and all other lines are assigned one after the other to environment variable `LastLine`. After this __FOR__ command line use `>myFile.txt echo(%LastLine%` to write just the last line to the file.

Comment: By the way: Most console applications with a progress indicator support an option to disable the progress indication. Therefore I recommend to read the documentation/manual/help of `myExecutable.exe`, especially the chapter about command line options. It could be that this executable supports also an option to disable progress indication for easier usage of the executable in a batch task.

Comment: not exactly overwriting (rather suppressing), but perhaps useful for you: `myExecutable.exe |findstr /RX "[0-9][0-9]* > myFile.txt`